# Can't define DQ and DT variable in Intel 8086 emulator

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I wanna to multiple 2 numbers,which have got 32bits.

I can define DD for each variables,but I can't define DQ variables for result in emu8086.

```
data_seg segment
    X DD 12341234H
    Y DD 11111111H
    Z DQ ?
    data_seg ends
```

It will return error in line number 4,which declare Z as DQ .

Can 8086 support DQ and DT type of variables?If it can,where is the problem?
(I'm using emu8086 to emulate my assembly code)

Comment: It is an error from your assembler, that has nothing to do with the emulator.  You didn't mention what assembler you use, shop for a better one.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm installing emu8086 in ubuntu wine.with out any thing else,but it has this problem in windows too.

Comment: Well, using the same assembler I'd guess.  Don't keep it a secret.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess, but as the 8086 can't natively handle quadwords or twords (no FPU) perhaps there is no sense in supporting such data sizes.